# How to properly link up a custom UITableViewCell and access elements

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm having an incredible amount of difficulty creating a custom UITableViewCell. I've checked stackoverflow and google thoroughly, but all the solutions posted are either incomplete, incorrect, or do go far enough.

So here's what I want to do. I want to have MyTableViewController load in custom cells, let's call them MyCustomCell, instead of the default cells. I want MyCustomCell to be a full fledged subclass of UITableViewCell, so I've got an .xib with just a UITableViewCell (and a few test labels inside of it). The cell identifier is set to "MyCustomCell" and the class is set to "MyCustomCell". I'm able to drag and link the labels up with MyCustomCell.h.

Back in MyTableViewController.m, I've got the following code

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *ident = @"MyCustomCell";

MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ident];//appears to crash here
if(cell == nil){
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:ident owner:self options:nil];
    for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[MyCustomCell class]]){
            cell = (MyCustomCell*)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}
cell.myCustomLabel.text = @"hello world";//myCustomLabel from the .xib is linked up to the 
//proper variable in MyCustomCell.h, and it's also being synthesized
//I'd like to modify all the custom labels,imageviews,etc here
return cell;
}
```

Running this gives me the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MyTableViewController 0x7d5ba80> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key myCustomLabel.'
```

This usually comes up when I've forgotten to hook something up with an .xib and it's .h file, or maybe when it's not synthesized, but I've checked and it seems to work out. Is there anything I'm doing wrong here? Do I have to do [[MyCustomCell alloc] init] or [[MyCustomCell alloc] initWithCustomMethod:...] at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targeting iOS 5, use this:

```
 [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"yourNibName" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"yourNibIdentifier"];
```

then, you just use the identifier to get the cell from the nib

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

and finally: make sure you are actually assigning the proper class name and the proper identifier to your UITableViewCell subclass's nib.

Comment: Your first suggestion didn't seem to work. I also went over the nib again and everything looked like it should work. In the end, I just deleted everything, started over, and now it looks like everything's hooked up just right